# How to interact with multiple S3 bucket from a single docker container?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3

I have a case of making multiple s3 buckets interact with each other from a docker container. For example I have an s3 bucket named ABCD and another named EFGH . Now I want to build a docker container inside which I need to copy data from ABCD to EFGH or in general do all the read write operations. I have role based access to these buckets as well as I have credentials like aws acess keys available. I am able to do this from my local machine but now need it to be done from the container

Comment: Up to some issues around credentials it should be basically identical.  What do you have now, and what problems are you running into?

Comment: @DavidMaze I actually dont have a docker file yet as I am still struggling to have one. Could you please post the DOckerfile if you have one ?